# ASP.Net MVC Constructor Injection with Autofac - Change Runtime ConnectionString

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

Need some help trying to solve a problem change connection string run time based on a parameter. I am using AutoFac dependency injection. User will log on and retrieve connection string from database and connect to respective server and database based on connection string. When I pass hard coded connection string, it works fine but I need to pass dynamic connection string Following is the code which is using for registration

```
 private static AutofacDependencyResolver SetAutofacContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {

        builder.RegisterType<DbFactory>().As<IDbFactory>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<Interface.Uow.IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();


      //  builder.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(connectionString));

        ////Repository
        builder.RegisterType<VoucherRepository>().As<Interface.Repository.IVoucherRepository>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<CustomerRepository>().As<Interface.Repository.ICustomerRepository>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<UserRepository>().As<Interface.Repository.IUserRepository>().InstancePerRequest();

        ////services
        builder.RegisterType<VoucherBusinessService>().As<IVoucherBusinessService>().InstancePerRequest().PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies);
        builder.RegisterType<CustomerBusinessService>().As<ICustomerBusinessService>().InstancePerRequest().PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies);
        builder.RegisterType<UserBusinessService>().As<IUserBusinessService>().InstancePerRequest().PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies);

        builder.RegisterType<DbFactory>().As<IDbFactory>().WithParameter("ConnectionString", "Data Source=TESTSERVER;Initial Catalog=TradingManagerClient;Integrated Security=True");

        Autofac.IContainer container = builder.Build();
        //DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        return new AutofacDependencyResolver(container);
}
```

Following is my DBFactory class

```
      public class DbFactory : Disposable, IDbFactory
{
    private CoreDbContext _coreDbContext = null;

    public DbFactory() 
    {
        //For CodeFirst It is required
        //Database.SetInitializer<CoreDbContext>(null);
    }

    private string conn;
    public DbFactory(string ConnectionString)
    {
        //For CodeFirst It is required
        //Database.SetInitializer<CoreDbContext>(null);
        this.conn = ConnectionString;
    }

    public CoreDbContext GetDbContext
    {
        get
        {
            return this._coreDbContext ?? (this._coreDbContext = new CoreDbContext(conn));
        }
    }

    protected override void DisposeCore()
    {
        if (this._coreDbContext != null)
            this._coreDbContext.Dispose();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the CoreDbContext
    /// </summary>
    public ICoreDbContext Get
    {
        get {  return GetDbContext; }
    }
}
```

I want to pass connection string to my DBFactory class on runtime. Do I need to handle it at controller level, if yes then how ?
Kindly guide in this regard.

Comment: what do you mean by `pass connection string to my DBFactory class on runtime` ? currently if you are passing `IDbFactory` to any controller's constructor it will resolve this with your current connectionstring which you have passed while registering type `builder.RegisterType<DbFactory>()...`

Comment: alternative you can do this using lambda expression as well `builder.Register(c => new DbFactory("ypurconnectionstring")).As<IDbFactory>();
`

Comment: @Curiousdev It will resolve with my current connection string which is hard coded for the time being but I need to register with dynamic connection string so any clue how can I do that ?

Comment: put your connection string in `Session["connectionString"]` or `app key` in `web.config` or `parameters table`

Comment: @ Curiousdev I have already put it into session but now how will I be able to resolve it at runtime ? Do I need to resolve it  at controller level ? If yes how ?

Comment: Dependencies are resolved in SetAutofacContainer which is fired only once when the application is started.